# How to Read the size of a Widget in the Layout Phase and Use the size for another widget in the Build Phase Before drawFrame()

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

The size of one of my widgets depends on the size of another one of my widgets (in a non standard way)
so what I am doing at the moment is using the Rect Getter Plugin and building the Widget Tree multiple times
(i do this by calling build inside build with an async function that waits for the current build to finish and then runs build again)

in my particular case the process goes like this ( or atleast this is what i believe given https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/WidgetsBinding/drawFrame.html)

1. build phase completes
2. the async function called in (build #1) calls build again while the layout phase from (1) runs as well
3. the async function called in (build #2) calls build again while
   the layout phase from (2) runs as well

because the layout phase from (1) has completed by the time (3) runs I now have the size of the desired widget and I can use it to set the size of the other widget
this works but I have a frame of flicker

so what I would like to do is

call the build phase once
call the layout phase and grab the desired size with RectGetter (which uses findRenderObject())
stop the automatic transition into the "The compositing bits phase"
run the build phase now with the size saved from the layout phase
this way the final phase that draws the frame wont run and the screen wont flicker

is this possible? If so could anybody point me in the right direction to do this? perhaps someone could help me with an example. or even some functions to look into.
any help is appreciated

---This is just ONE of the specific cases that I am working with

```
new Scaffold(
    body: new Flex(
      direction: (isWidthMax) ? Axis.vertical : Axis.horizontal,
      //ONLY relevant if position is top or bottom
      textDirection: (position == sheetPosition.right)
          ? TextDirection.ltr
          : TextDirection.rtl,
      //ONLY relevant if position is left or right
      verticalDirection: (position == sheetPosition.top)
          ? VerticalDirection.up
          : VerticalDirection.down,
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
      children: <Widget>[
        new Flexible(
            fit: FlexFit.loose,
            child: new Container(
              color: Colors.red,
            )),
        new RectGetter(
          key: objOneKey,
          child: new ConstrainedBox( //tag: WIDGET 1
            constraints: _calcBoxConstraints(isWidthMax),
            child: new Container(
              color: Colors.purple,
              child: new Flex(
                direction: (isWidthMax) ? Axis.vertical : Axis.horizontal,
                //ONLY relevant if position is top or bottom
                textDirection: (position == sheetPosition.right)
                    ? (placement == attachmentPlacement.inside)
                        ? TextDirection.rtl
                        : TextDirection.ltr
                    : (placement == attachmentPlacement.inside)
                        ? TextDirection.ltr
                        : TextDirection.rtl,
                //ONLY relevant if position is left or right
                verticalDirection: (position == sheetPosition.top)
                    ? (placement == attachmentPlacement.inside)
                        ? VerticalDirection.down
                        : VerticalDirection.up
                    : (placement == attachmentPlacement.inside)
                        ? VerticalDirection.up
                        : VerticalDirection.down,
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                children: <Widget>[
                  new Container( //tag: WIDGET 2
                    color: Colors.amberAccent,
                    child: sheet,
                  ),
                  new Flexible( //tag: WIDGET 3
                    fit: FlexFit.loose,
                    child: new Container(
                      color: Colors.greenAccent,
                      child: (attachment != null) ? attachment : null,
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  );
```

in the code above there are 3 widgets "taged" with comments
WIDGET 1, WIDGET 2, and WIDGET 3
after the initial build phase I should be able to grab the size of WIDGET 1 and WIDGET 3 by using findRenderObject() (because this size is calculated during the build phase and I can reference the widget by saving a key, or just using the Rect Getter Plug In which does that for you)
then I would like to save the values and stop the other phases from running so that what I built (which is partially off because I have yet to use the sizes grabbed in the layout phase) does NOT display by running drawFrame()
then I would like to run the build function again but this time I pass WIDGET 2 a size that was calculated by using the sizes of WIDGET 1 and WIDGET 3 grabbed previously

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want a LayoutBuilder and/or a CustomMultiChildLayout.